# One hot encode correlations and decision trees

Tags: python, pandas, correlation, decision-tree

I have few questions about preparing the data for learning.
Im very confused about how to convert columns to categorical and binary columns when i want to use the for  correlations and classifier decision tree.

for exmaple in NBA_df, convert the position column to categorical column for using decision tree, can i convert it to categorical with `.astype('category').cat.codes`? (I know in basketball you can note the position by number 1-5.
[NBA_df](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0iuzS.png)

And in students_df why its more correct to convert the 'gender','race/ethnicity','lunch','test preparation course' columns to a new binary columns with `.get_dummies` and not do the categorical convert in the same column ?
[students_df](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qbpQX.png)

Its same in correlation and trees?

Comment: Note that while you might find answers here, you also might have better luck on the [data science stack exchange](https://datascience.stackexchange.com/). Consider posing your question there.

Comment: Yeah, this is a DS question.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure I totally understand what you mean by converting to categorical "in the same column", but I assume you mean replacing the categorical response from positions into numbers 1 through 5 and keeping those numbers in the same column.

Assuming this is what you meant, you have to think about how the computer will interpret the input. Is a Small Forward (position 3 in basketball) 3 times a Point Guard (1 * 3)? Of course not, but a computer will see it that way. It will determine relationships with the target that are not realistic. For this reason, you need separate columns with a binary indicator like `.get_dummies` is doing. That way, the computer will not see the positions as numeric values that can be operated on, but it will see the positions as separate entities.

Comment: Ok, in other df if for example  i need to convert 100 countries?  i

Comment: Yes, pandas.get_dummies() would output 100 columns.